# luigi per-task retry policy

Tags: python, luigi

I have an issue configuring luigi per-task retry-policy. I've configured the global luigi.cfg file as follows:

```
[scheduler]
retry-delay: 1
retry_count: 5

[worker]
keep_alive: true
wait_interval: 3
```

Furthermore, it states in the luigi configuration manual that writing a task as follows:

```
class SomeTask(luigi.Task):

   retry_count = 3
```

will suffice in overriding the luigi retry_count specified in the luigi.cfg. However this setting does not effect the run at all. I've managed to create a task which fails every time just for testing, and logging returns that this task failed 5 times (and not 3).

I think there's something fundamental i'm missing.

Comment: don't have a real solution here, but do the retry examples work for you? https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/bfb62337011ec24ceda7eece5e8526aa57d1cf06/examples/per_task_retry_policy.py

Comment: @MattMcKnight well, actually the do not...

Comment: I have confirmed the same problem, I am sending a pull request. https://github.com/spotify/luigi/pull/2012

Answer (score 0):

If even the example does not work. I believe your server or client code is out of date. Note that the `luigi` command will run your installed version and the central server needs to be restarted after a package upgrade.